# C# divide operator not Working

Tags: c#, operators

My problem is that this:" **Zinsen = Zinsen / 100;** "is not working! 
i dont know why but it woud be helpful if you can Help me :D
After i run my Programm zinsen is "0".

Thanks

```
 Kontostand = Convert.ToInt32(StrKontostand);
            Laufzeit = Convert.ToInt32(StrLaufzeit);
            Zinsen = Convert.ToInt32(Strzinsen);

            Zinsen = Zinsen / 100;
            while (Loops <= Laufzeit)
            {
                Loops = Loops + 1;
                Kontostand = Kontostand + (Kontostand * Zinsen);

            } 
                ErgebnisStr = Convert.ToString(Kontostand);
            lblErgebnis.Text = ErgebnisStr;
```

Comment: Dividing an integer with another integer produces an integer, it is a well known rule

Comment: `Int` division works like this: `99/100` will result in `0`. What are you expecting?